# Reference worksheet by cell value?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a formula that references a value on another worksheet.  Something like this:

```
=('sheet1'!C5)
```

However, I don't always know what sheet it will be on.  I have another cell on the main sheet ('mainsheet') that has a value of "sheet1".  Let's say it's `A1`.  So how can I dynamically reference cell `C5` of sheet1 using the value of `A1` on "mainsheet"?

I tried `=(''&A1&''!C5)` but it doesn't work.

Comment: You can't do this with just formulas. You can however with VBA. Are you interested in a VBA solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`INDIRECT`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) to set a reference dynamically.

```
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(A1,"!","C5"))
```